# problems filling a field via geckoFX

Tags: c#, geckofx

I'm trying to fill an input with geckofx but I'm having a hard time. I can find the element, send the command to fill, but it looks like it has something doing the validation. To work I need to manually click the input and then click out of it.

```
var input = new GeckoInputElement(Browser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("md-input")[0].DomObject);
input.Value = "myvalue@gmail.com";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review how to ask a good question on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can get more attention and help if you share what you've tried and what the expected results look like.

Comment: When do you populate the input field? After the page has been fully loaded on `DocumentCompleted`?